How to access API data for lead traders on Binance (Copy Trading)?
I'm currently working on a project that involves analyzing and predicting trades from leading traders on Binance's copy trading platform. However, I’ve noticed that Binance’s public APIs don’t seem to provide endpoints for retrieving detailed information about leading traders and their positions, strategies, or historical performance.
I would like to know if:

There are existing APIs or workarounds that can provide data on
leading traders for copy trading.

Any third-party tools or services can help fetch such data.

If Binance plans to offer API support for this in the future, where
can I find more information about upcoming API changes? I want to
collect data on traders' historical trades, PnL, ROE, and strategies
to build a predictive model.


Or is there any marketplace that support those features for copy traders, other than Binance?
Any insights or suggestions are greatly appreciated!
